# Чёрный как уголь

Tags: пунктуация

Устойчивое сочетание? Запятая не нужна?

«... и его чёрные как уголь глаза...»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение " черный как уголь" ( без запятой)  является фразеологизмом. В значении " очень черный либо очень грязный)". Но может быть и свободным сравнением. Ср.: Она смотрела на него сверху вниз, ласково ***улыбаясь чёрными, как угли, цыганскими глазами***. (М.Горький).

Comment: Но в вашем примере запятая нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Это не фразеологизм, запятые нужны. Две, а не одна.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, сравнительный оборот, выраженный устойчивым оборотом (или же фразеологизмом), не выделяется запятой.

Пример:

> Сильный как бык.

Только что нашёл Вашу фразу в онлайн-словаре: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/195948/%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Подробно, если хотите, можете почитать здесь: http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183